# label for="" tag in Firefox !

Tags: html

```
<label id="hhaaaa" for='<%= hh.ClientID %>'>
    <table style="height: 100px; width: 300px;cursor: pointer" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="jhuu" onmouseover="Highlight(this.id,true,'ss');" onmouseout="Highlight(this.id,false,'ss');" class="asdqweqwe">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="height: 10px">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" style="width: 20px; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 7px"><input id="hh" runat="server" type="checkbox" /></td>
                        <td style="width: 60px" valign="top" align="center"><img src="" /></td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><span style="font-weight: bold;"></span><img alt="" id="asd" onclick="" style="cursor: pointer" src="" /></span><br /><span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="height: 10px">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </label>
```

Hello i write this code to make  a check box label this code run in all Browser Except Firefox ???!!!!

Comment: what happens in firefox?

Comment: You're trying to make the whole table a label??

Comment: have you tried running it through [the W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/)? That might pick up the problem.

Comment: @Spudley - that's what I did :)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The `Label` can't contain the element it's labeling, it's simply wrong.</strike>
(Thanks erKURITA :))

Try something like this first and see if it works fine:

```
<label id="hhaaaa" for="<%= hh.ClientID %>">Some description here..</label>
```

As far as I know `Label` is an *inline* element so to have it contain other elements add `display: block;` CSS to it although it's not very elegant and probably against standards.

Comment: Actually, it can:

"The label represents a caption in a user interface. The caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as the label element's labeled control, either using for attribute, or by putting the form control inside the label element itself.

If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a labelable form-associated element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree order is the label element's labeled control."

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is the problem:

```
<td align="left" valign="top"><span style="font-weight: bold;"></span><img alt="" id="asd" onclick="" style="cursor: pointer" src="" /></span><br /><span></span></td>
```

Remove the span end tag that is not open.

```
<td align="left" valign="top"><span style="font-weight: bold;"></span><img alt="" id="asd" style="cursor: pointer" src="" /><br /><span></span></td>
```